# How do i make a simple web based notepad application

Tags: textbox

I have to make formatting available for a text box in a web based application just like the options available here to make selected text bold or in italics. I don't know where to start. can anyone please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use something that already exists:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of ten different rich text editors that will do what you need.
http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're going to be coding in, but I'm sure most languages have built-in types for text boxes that can handle formatted text (not unlike the one I'm typing in right now), and probably have a method that returns the contents of the box.

All you'd need is to figure out is the format code, if you want to store this text and open it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create from "scratch", you can use any JavaScript framework to ease your work. There are many "good" frameworks out there:
jQuery, ExtJS, GWT, YUI, etc. Just choose the one that suits to your need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks